# jxl.read.biff.NumberValue cannot be cast to Collection

Tags: java, jxl

Iam just newbee to java,When I try to store read columns in Array List Iam getting this Exception  jxl.read.biff.NumberValue cannot be cast to Collection.ExcelReader .Please suggest me the mistake done by me.Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
class ExcelReader {
    private Workbook workbook;
    private Sheet sheet;
    ArrayList<ExcelReader> getRollNo=new ArrayList<Excelreader>;
    public  void getExcelContents() throws BiffException, IOException, WriteException
    {
        workbook= Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C://Student_Record.xls"));
        sheet=workbook.getSheet(0);
        int rowLen=sheet.getRows();
        for(int i=1;i<rowLen;i++ )
        {
            getRollNo.add((ExcelReader)sheet.getCell(1,i));
        System.out.println(getRollNo);
        }
    }

}
```

Main Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
public class MainExcelReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, WriteException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ExcelReader er=new ExcelReader();
        er.getExcelContents();

    }

}
```

Comment: Try using this for loop, hope it works.  for (int i = 1; i < rowLen; i++) {
            Cell cell = this.sheet.getCell(1, i);

            this.getRollNo.add(cell.getContents());
            System.out.println(this.getRollNo);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for loop in getcontents method, hope it works.

```
for (int i = 1; i < rowLen; i++) {
            Cell cell = this.sheet.getCell(1, i);

            this.getRollNo.add(cell.getContents());
            System.out.println(this.getRollNo);
        }
```